# Looping regressions by group_id using only observations in a certain estimation window and adding back the predictions to the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to learn how to perform some operations in python 3.7 that I usually do easily in Stata.

I am working on a dataframe like this:

```
estimation_window    group_id         y            x   
0                       1             3.17         23
1                       1             4.76         26
1                       2             4.17         73
1                       2             8.70         72
0                       2             11.45        16
```

I would like to have a for loop estimating a linear regression (y on x) for each different group in group_id, using only the observation that have the dummy estimation_window equal to 1.

Then, I would like to have three columns added back to my initial dataframe: one with predicted values, one with beta of each regression (x coefficient) and one with intercept of each regression. These values should be calculated for all the observations and not just the ones with the dummy estimation_window equal to 1.

The resulting dataset should look like this:

```
estimation_window    group_id         y            x        predicted_val    beta_coeff  alpha_coeff
0                       1             3.17         23           3.10            0.32         1.43        
1                       1             4.76         26           4.00            0.32         1.43
1                       2             4.17         73           4.10            0.75         0.95
1                       2             8.70         72           8.50            0.75         0.95
0                       2             11.45        16           10.30           0.75         0.95
```

I tried  using statsmodels but was not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have your dataframe:

```
>>> data
   estimation_window  group_id      y     x
0                  0         1   3.17  23.0
1                  1         1   4.76  26.0
2                  1         2   4.17  73.0
3                  1         2   8.70  72.0
4                  0         2  11.45  16.0
```

Then you can group-by the `group_id`, and do linear regression one by one and save up the parameters. If you're using `statsmodels`, this is what you can do:

```
for groupid, grp in data.groupby('group_id'):
    print(groupid)
    model = sm.OLS(grp['y'], sm.add_constant(grp['x'])).fit()
    data.loc[data['group_id'].eq(groupid), 'alpha'] = model.params['const']
    data.loc[data['group_id'].eq(groupid), 'beta'] = model.params['x']
```

Then you can recompute the predicted value manually (just because the linear model is simple):

```
data['predicted_val'] = data['x'] * data['beta'] + data['alpha']
```

and you have this as a result:

```
   estimation_window  group_id      y     x      alpha      beta  predicted_val
0                  0         1   3.17  23.0  -9.020000  0.530000       3.170000
1                  1         1   4.76  26.0  -9.020000  0.530000       4.760000
2                  1         2   4.17  73.0  12.926162 -0.089804       6.370451
3                  1         2   8.70  72.0  12.926162 -0.089804       6.460255
4                  0         2  11.45  16.0  12.926162 -0.089804      11.489294
```

Comment: Thanks, this would be good. The only part that seems to be missing is to estimate the regression by using only the rows that have the dummy estimation_window equal to 1.

Comment: Then you can shortlist those rows in `grp`, which is just like a dataframe, before passing onto `OLS()`